# Dynamic Database use in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to select data from a table which exists on multiple databases. I put the server name and the database name in an excel file, then I create a function in PowerBI: see the screenshot[image: Parameters].

I have an authentication problem:Foreach time it tries to connect to different databases, I need to validate this connection process manually: see screenshot [image: Authorization error]

My question is: how to make this validation process automatic?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Options and Disable it, like shown here:
[image: Options - Security]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, I have uncheked the chekbox.

A new message box appears asking me to put authentication information, and I must click on OK to make the query running: see screenshot

How to make this process also automatic?

[image]

[image: Authentication error]

Comment: That I haven't seen, but I don't really understand what it says because I don't know french. Try to look for that specific error on Power BI forum

Comment: We can't connect to the dataSource because of encrypted connection, do you have any idea about how to skip this popup window automaticaly?